# Chart.js: Chart not resizing in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, chart.js

I am trying to show multiple diagrams/charts at the same time using chart.js.
For my setup, I have one **chart.html** file which displays the diagram and a **split.html** file which creates multiple iframes (2 so far) and loads the **chart.html** in them.
When opening the **chart.html** directly, the resizing works, but when loaded in iframe it doesn't.
I could only imagine the error at chart.js since the sizing itself is already weird. It orients on the next "higher" element (div with fixed 100% width and height in my case) and setting width or height directly on the canvas doesnt change anything, see code below.

**chart.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/diagram.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
        <canvas id="diagram"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

**split.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/splitter.css" />
    <script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/splitter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>
```

**diagram.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var ctx = document.getElementById("diagram");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: /** excluded (unimportance) **/
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
// Resize chart
$(window).resize(function() {
    console.log("resize works!");
    if(myChart) myChart.update();
});
});
```

**splitter.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
const splits = 2;
switch (splits) {
    case 2:
        $("#content").append(
            $('<iframe />')
                .attr("id", "frame1")
                .attr("src", "./chart.html")
                .addClass("width50 height100")
        );
        $("#content").append(
            $('<iframe />')
                .attr("id", "frame2")
                .attr("src", "./chart.html")
                .addClass("width50 height100 left50")
        );
        break;
}
});
```

**splitter.css**:

```
iframe {
position: fixed;
border: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.width100 {
width: 100%;
}
.height100 {
height: 100%;
}
.width50 {
width: 50%;
}
.height50 {
height: 50%;
}
.left50 {
left: 50%;
}
.top50 {
top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Is there a special reason behind using iframes?

Comment: No, but what would be the better way?

Answer (score 1):

Change iframes to divs with modifiing your splitter.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
const splits = 2;
for(var i = 0; i < splits;i++){
    var chartContainer = $('<div id="frame' + (i + 1) + '"></div>').appendTo("#content");
    var canvas = $('<canvas class="diagram">').appendTo(chartContainer);
    if(i === 0)
        chartContainer.addClass('width50 height100');
    else
        chartContainer.addClass('width50 height100 left50');
}
});
```

It will add two divs to the content element instead of iframes and also put the canvases into the divs.
Than change your diagram.js to foreach over the canvases and make them work as a chart:

```
$('canvas.diagram').each(function(){
var ctx = $(this);
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  //here comes the chart configuration...
});
});
```

Change your css to align the two div next to each other with

```
.width50 {
width: 50%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

So the charts are now inside block elements and because of they're set to be responsive if you resize the window they will be resized automatically based on their parent elements' width (so you can remove the resizing part from your script too)